# Why is the Card-Flip is not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

When I am applying hover on the card container it is not working or it is not flipping but I when I remove the hover it flips to the back side, I have tried everything that I know but still no progress on that.
`

```
import React from 'react'
import './Summary.css'

function Summary() {
  return (
    <div className='summary'>
        <img className="body__image" src={require("./Images/background3Color.jpg")}></img>
        <div className='box__container'>
            <div className='boxes'>
                <div className='box__inner'>
                    <div className='box__front'>
                        <img className='boxes__pics' src={require('./Images/AboutMe.jpg')}></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className='box__back'>
                        <div className='headline'></div>
                        <div className='education'>
                            <h2>Bachelor Of Technology in Computer Science and Tech.</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className='work-ex'>
                            <p>Worked as an Application Dvelopment Associate in Accenture for 1 year</p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='boxes'>
                <div className='box__inner'>
                    <div className='box__front'>
                        <img className='boxes__pics' src={require('./Images/Contacts.jpg')}></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className='box__back'>
                        <div className='headline'></div>
                        <div className='education'>
                            <h2>Bachelor Of Technology in Computer Science and Tech.</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className='work-ex'>
                            <p>Worked as an Application Dvelopment Associate in Accenture for 1 year</p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Summary
```

`

I was expecting the flip will work but to no avail.

I have tried to add hover to both box__inner and boxes container but still it would not flip.

Here is what I tried:

`

```
.summary{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1;
}
.body__image{
    height: 100vh;
}
.box__container{
    position: absolute;
    /* background-color: aqua; */
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* opacity: 0.4; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
.boxes{
    height: 320px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(107,186,167,0.7);
    perspective: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box__inner{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.boxes__pics{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.box__inner:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.box__front, .box__back{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
} 
.box__front{

}
.box__back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The z-index was causing the main problem after removing it from the parent div the hover effect worked fine.